# How can we detect anomalies in real-time using MindsDB?

Tags: machine-learning, real-time, clickhouse, anomaly-detection, mindsdb

I have a clickhouse database which consists of tables which update in real time. I want to detect anomalies in real time when the tables update. For this purpose I am using MindsDB to create an AI table to predict the anomalies. But I am not sure how to deploy it and how to get results out of it.

I created a table with an extra target column as ‘anomaly’ using `case when` statements, and created a model. I want to know how to test my model and how it can automatically detect anomalies and how it can be deployed. And also how can I use unsupervised algorithms rather than going and creating a table with anomaly target.

Comment: hi Rithvik - a broad set of questions here, sounds like a cool project. I don't have all the answers for you, but it sounds like you should be using Materialized Views or Cascading Materialized Views in ClickHouse to update these tables in real time: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/developer/cascading-materialized-views - I'm sure you've already seen this blog from MindsDB and ClickHouse so listing here for completeness https://clickhouse.com/blog/how-to-enable-predictive-capabilities-in-clickhouse-databases https://mindsdb.com/blog/enabling-predictive-capabilities-in-clickhouse-database